# Need help in using if condition using windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Need help in using if condition to set the value of variable in windows batch file

the code I am using  is

```
:: This is Code for D3
@echo off
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateADD("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& 
right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "filename=%MM%%DD%%YYYY%"
echo "%YYYY%" 
set /a "YYYY-=1"
echo "%YYYY%" 
pause
```

In the above code I want to modify such that if the month is Jan , Feb and March then the value of YYYY should be YYYY-=1 that is previous year 2017,  else the value should be current year 2018.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to do that in batch rather than VBScript, where it would several orders of magnitude easier?

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't use `if "%MM%" leq "03"`?

Comment: this is just a test code, the main code we are using is moving files from one folder to another based on dates. we have created a windows scheduling task to do that. our main objective is to achieve functionality that if file name is like filename=%MM%%DD%%YYYY% then it should move files. we found a bug in the code since company's financial year is from April 1 to March 31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `set /a "YYYY-=1"` with `if "%MM%" leq "03" set /a "YYYY-=1"`, so it will decrease the year only if month is Jan, Feb or Mar.

Note: as you are using `YYYY` as "current year", you should give the new variable another name, like `FYEAR` (for "FiscalYear") to avoid confusion). Your code will work fine without that, but if you have a problem with the code next year, you will be glad to have it named with a "speaking name".

Comment: Code works. but would you mind please explaining me what is this leq, since I am not a vb programmer , just incase if I want to check if month is greater than march..Thanks

Comment: @mb1987, `leq` is batch-file operator syntax for `less than or equal`. At a CMD prompt, type `if /?` for information about these operators.